# Separate traffic between two tun+ devices with openvpn

Tags: openvpn, route

I'm running two OpenVPN clients, so I have two `tun` interfaces configured.

Each of the `tun` interfaces has a different subnet. One of the interfaces, let's say `tun1` has a default route, so most of my traffic goes through there.

My `tun0` interface however, does not have a default route, so only packets to it's subnet are routed through this interface.

The problem is that packets that are supposed to go through `tun0` => `eth0`, are going through `tun0` => `tun1` => `eth0`. This does make sense, because `tun1` is used as a default device.

How can I prevent packets in my private network from being routed through both VPNs and make them routed only through one of the VPNs?

Update:

Here is my current routing table:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.4.102.81 dev tun1 
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.4.0.1 via 10.4.102.81 dev tun1 
10.4.102.81 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.4.102.82 
10.176.128.0/18 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.177.0.0/18 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.177.128.0/18 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.178.0.0/16 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.179.0.0/16 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.180.0.0/16 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.181.0.0/16 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
10.183.0.0/16 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
46.165.208.65 via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.4.102.81 dev tun1 
172.29.0.0/22 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
172.29.2.77 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.29.2.78 
172.31.0.0/22 via 172.29.2.77 dev tun0 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.76  metric 1
```

Comment: Can you post your routes (=output of `ip r`) and the subnet IPs, please?

Comment: What is the source and destination of the traffic that's routing through the tunnels?

Comment: tun1 not has default route. 0.0.0.0/1 - just half of all ipv4 diapason.

Comment: Yes that is the first line, then I have 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.4.102.81 dev tun1 for the second half

Answer (score 1):

You should add a route for the remote VPN servers (the tun0 one):

```
ip add route $ip_of_the_vpn_server via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0
```

or more generically:

```
ip add route $(ip route get $ip_of_the_vpn_server | head -n1)
```

before starting the VPN.

This will ensure that all packets to this VPN server will be sent by your non-VPN-default route.